# Guardar fila de consulta SQL en variables

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, vb.net

Actualmente desarrollo una aplicación con el uso de BD, tengo una BD con una tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi código es el siguiente para realizar la consulta:

```
Private Sub ReadQuery()

 Dim Usuario as string
 Dima TSK as string
 Dim ConectionInfo As New SqlConnection(datos de conexion)

    Try

        'Creamos el comando
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = ConectionInfo.CreateCommand()

        'Construimos la consulta 

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [DBTSK].[dbo].[TSKusers] WHERE [User] = 'Karina Ortiz'"

        'Abrimos la conexión
        ConectionInfo.Open()

        'Ejecutamos la consulta
        Dim value As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        'Pasamos el valor a la variable
        Usuario = Convert.ToString(value)

        'Mostramos el valor de la variable
        MessageBox.Show(Usuario)

        'cerramos la conexión
        ConectionInfo.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Se ha producido un error.
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End sub
```

Me guarda el usuario en una variable, pero si quisiera agregar mas variables como TSK, loginDate y loginTime, ¿Cómo puedo guardar los valores de esas celdas en cada una de estas nuevas variables?

Algo así como guardar toda la consulta de una fila en variables, sin repetir todo el try para otra variables... como un arreglo o vector.

Comment: Creo que esto te será de utilidad: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/sqlserverya/

Answer (score 1):

En `System.Data` tienes objetos muy interesantes para ello: DataSet, DataTable por ejemplo.
Después de abrir la conexión debes declarar un `SqlDataAdapter` que traerá todos los resultados de tu consulta (filas y columnas). Con él, rellenas por ejemplo un DataTable, que en realidad es una tabla en memoria, y ya dispones de todas las columnas.

```
Dim sql as string = "SELECT * FROM [DBTSK].[dbo].[TSKusers] WHERE [User] = 'Karina Ortiz'"
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql , ConectionInfo)  
Dim dtDatos As DataTable = New DataTable  
adapter.Fill(dtDatos)
Dim User as string = dtDatos.rows(0)("User")
Dim loginDate as date = dtDatos.rows(0)("loginDate")
```

Si la consulta devuelve más de una fila, podrías iterar las filas (rows).

```
For i as integer = 0 to dtDatos.Rows.Count-1
   Dim User as string = dtDatos.rows(i)("User")
   Dim loginDate as date = dtDatos.rows(i)("loginDate")
Next
```

Si quieres saber los datos de todas las columnas y filas, iteras las unas y las otras

```
For i as integer = 0 to dtDatos.Rows.Count-1
  For j as integer = 0 to dtDatos.Columns.Count-1
     Dim Dato = dtDatos.rows(i)(j)
     dim msg as string = "Dato de la fila " & i.ToString & " y columna " & dtDatos.Columns(j).ColumName 

  Next
Next
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! me funcionó perfecto.
Voy comenzando con implementaciones de BD (SQL)a aplicaciones con VB.Net, deberé leer más documentación para seguir aprendiendo.